# Compare Python Pandas DataFrames for matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, rows, matching

I have this DataFrame (`df1`) in Pandas:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
print df1

       A         B         C         D
0.860379  0.726956  0.394529  0.833217
0.014180  0.813828  0.559891  0.339647
0.782838  0.698993  0.551252  0.361034
0.833370  0.982056  0.741821  0.006864
0.855955  0.546562  0.270425  0.136006
0.491538  0.445024  0.971603  0.690001
0.911696  0.065338  0.796946  0.853456
0.744923  0.545661  0.492739  0.337628
0.576235  0.219831  0.946772  0.752403
0.164873  0.454862  0.745890  0.437729
```

I would like to check if any row (all columns) from another dataframe (`df2`) are present in `df1`. Here is `df2`:

```
df2 = df1.ix[4:8]
df2.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df2.loc[-1] = [2, 3, 4, 5]
df2.loc[-2] = [14, 15, 16, 17]
df2.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
print df2

           A         B         C         D
    0.855955  0.546562  0.270425  0.136006
    0.491538  0.445024  0.971603  0.690001
    0.911696  0.065338  0.796946  0.853456
    0.744923  0.545661  0.492739  0.337628
    0.576235  0.219831  0.946772  0.752403
    2.000000  3.000000  4.000000  5.000000
   14.000000 15.000000 16.000000 17.000000
```

I tried using `df.lookup` to search for one row at a time. I did it this way:

```
list1 = df2.ix[0].tolist()
cols = df1.columns.tolist()
print df1.lookup(list1, cols)
```

but I got this error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print df1.lookup(list1, cols)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2217, in lookup
    raise KeyError('One or more row labels was not found')
KeyError: 'One or more row labels was not found'
```

I also tried `.all()` using:

```
print (df2 == df1).all(1).any()
```

but I got this error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (df2 == df1).all(1).any()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 884, in f
    return self._compare_frame(other, func, str_rep)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3010, in _compare_frame
    raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

I also tried `isin()` like this:

```
print df2.isin(df1)
```

but I got `False` everywhere, which is not correct:

```
    A      B      C      D
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
False  False  False  False
```

Is it possible to search for a set of rows in a DataFrame, by comparing it to another dataframe's rows?

EDIT:
Is is possible to drop `df2` rows if those rows are also present in `df1`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem would be to use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/merging.html).  Checking if any row (all columns) from another dataframe (df2) are present in df1 is equivalent to determining the intersection of the the two dataframes.  This can be accomplished using the following function:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], how='inner')
```

For example, if df1 was

```
    A           B            C          D
0   0.403846    0.312230    0.209882    0.397923
1   0.934957    0.731730    0.484712    0.734747
2   0.588245    0.961589    0.910292    0.382072
3   0.534226    0.276908    0.323282    0.629398
4   0.259533    0.277465    0.043652    0.925743
5   0.667415    0.051182    0.928655    0.737673
6   0.217923    0.665446    0.224268    0.772592
7   0.023578    0.561884    0.615515    0.362084
8   0.346373    0.375366    0.083003    0.663622
9   0.352584    0.103263    0.661686    0.246862
```

and df2 was defined as:

```
     A          B            C           D
0   0.259533    0.277465    0.043652    0.925743
1   0.667415    0.051182    0.928655    0.737673
2   0.217923    0.665446    0.224268    0.772592
3   0.023578    0.561884    0.615515    0.362084
4   0.346373    0.375366    0.083003    0.663622
5   2.000000    3.000000    4.000000    5.000000
6   14.000000   15.000000   16.000000   17.000000
```

The function `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], how='inner')` produces:

```
     A           B           C           D
0   0.259533    0.277465    0.043652    0.925743
1   0.667415    0.051182    0.928655    0.737673
2   0.217923    0.665446    0.224268    0.772592
3   0.023578    0.561884    0.615515    0.362084
4   0.346373    0.375366    0.083003    0.663622
```

The results are all of the rows (all columns) that are both in df1 and df2.

We can also modify this example if the columns are not the same in df1 and df2 and just compare the row values that are the same for a subset of the columns.  If we modify the original example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = df1.ix[4:8]
df2.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df2.loc[-1] = [2, 3, 4, 5]
df2.loc[-2] = [14, 15, 16, 17]
df2.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df2 = df2[['A', 'B', 'C']] # df2 has only columns A B C
```

Then we can look at the common columns using `common_cols = list(set(df1.columns) & set(df2.columns))` between the two dataframes then merge:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=common_cols, how='inner')
```

**EDIT:** New question (comments), having identified the rows from df2 that were also present in the first dataframe (df1), is it possible to take the result of the pd.merge() and to then drop the rows from df2 that are also present in df1

I do not know of a straightforward way to accomplish the task of dropping the rows from df2 that are also present in df1.  That said, you could use the following:

```
ds1 = set(tuple(line) for line in df1.values)
ds2 = set(tuple(line) for line in df2.values)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(ds2.difference(ds1)), columns=df2.columns)
```

There probably exists a better way to accomplish that task but i am unaware of such a method / function.

**EDIT 2:** How to drop the rows from df2 that are also present in df1 as shown in @WR answer.

The method provided `df2[~df2['A'].isin(df12['A'])]` does not account for all types of situations.  Consider the following DataFrames:

df1:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  6  4  1  6
1  7  6  6  8
2  1  6  2  7
3  8  0  4  1
4  1  0  2  3
5  8  4  7  5
6  4  7  1  1
7  3  7  3  4
8  5  2  8  8
9  3  2  8  4
```

df2:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  3
1  8  4  7  5
2  4  7  1  1
3  3  7  3  4
4  5  2  8  8
5  1  1  1  1
6  2  2  2  2
```

df12:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  3
1  8  4  7  5
2  4  7  1  1
3  3  7  3  4
4  5  2  8  8
```

Using the above DataFrames with the goal of dropping rows from df2 that are also present in df1 would result in the following:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
```

Rows (1, 1, 1, 1) and (2, 2, 2, 2) are in df2 and not in df1.  Unfortunately, using the provided method (`df2[~df2['A'].isin(df12['A'])]`) results in:

```
   A  B  C  D
6  2  2  2  2
```

This occurs because the value of 1 in column A is found in both the intersection DataFrame (i.e. (1, 0, 2, 3)) and df2 and thus removes both (1, 0, 2, 3) and (1, 1, 1, 1).  This is unintended since the row (1, 1, 1, 1) is not in df1 and should not be removed.

I think the following will provide a solution.  It creates a dummy column that is later used to subset the DataFrame to the desired results:

```
df12['key'] = 'x'
temp_df = pd.merge(df2, df12, on=df2.columns.tolist(), how='left')
temp_df[temp_df['key'].isnull()].drop('key', axis=1)
```

Comment: Oh ofcourse! An SQL `INNER JOIN`. That escaped me. One problem is that I have never used it for `JOIN`ing `ON` multiple columns. If all the dataframe's columns are to be checked, could you replace your `on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` with `on=df1.columns`?

Comment: You could use `on=list(df1.columns)` or equivalently `on=list(df2.columns)`.  If you want to check that the rows are the same (all columns), the columns in df1 and df2 must be the same.

Comment: Andrew, one last question (I also added it to the original post) - having identified the rows from `df2` that were also present in the first dataframe (`df1`), is it possible to take the result of the `pd.merge()` and to then drop the rows from `df2` that are also present in `df1`?

Comment: In EDIT 2, it seems like right now you have the two starting dataframes as `df12` and `df2`. Did you mean `df2['key'] = 'x'` and `temp_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on=df2.col......`. I

Comment: From the example above, pd.merge() should generate <= number of items than are in `max(len(df1), len(df2))`. When I do `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.columns.tolist()[:-1], how='inner')`, I get output that is `> max(len(df1),  len(df2))`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 13):

@Andrew: I believe I found a way to drop the rows of one dataframe that are already present in another (i.e. to answer my EDIT) without using loops - let me know if you disagree and/or if my OP + EDIT did not clearly state this:

**THIS WORKS**

The columns for both dataframes are always the same - `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. With this in mind, based heavily on Andrew's approach, here is how to drop the rows from `df2` that are also present in `df1`:

```
common_cols = df1.columns.tolist()                         #generate list of column names
df12 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=common_cols, how='inner')     #extract common rows with merge
df2 = df2[~df2['A'].isin(df12['A'])]
```

Line 3 does the following:

- Extract only rows from `df2` that do not match rows in `df1`:
- In order for 2 rows to be different, ANY one column of one row must
  necessarily be different that the **corresponding** column in another
  row.
- Here, I picked column `A` to make this comparison - it is
  possible to use any of the column names, but **not** ALL of the
  column names.

NOTE: this method is essentially the equivalent of the SQL `NOT IN()`.

Comment: You cannot imagine how much time I wasted trying to use loops to accomplish this.

Comment: I think you may have an issue with your logic (though I may be misinterpreting your desired results)  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You are correct. Yours is a better solution. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: what is the meaning of '~' operater in this commend?  df2 = df2[~df2['A'].isin(df12['A'])]

Comment: It means column `A` values from `df2` that are **not** in column `A` from `df12`.

Comment: @edesz pandas has a drop_duplicates function which might be more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I'm adding these notes for myself for later...

Use pd.concat() and then remove duplicates.

Combine two DataFrames

`df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])`

Dataframe of duplicated rows

`df3[df3.duplicated()]`

Dataframe of DISTINCT rows from both dataframes

`df3.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop='index')`

To answer this question explicitly, I would do the following:

```
# set a new column to label the dataframes
df1['df'] = 'df1'
df2['df'] = 'df2'
# combine dataframes
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2)])
# setting duplicated(keep=False) keeps all duplicated rows from both dataframes 
# then we can set a mask to just show the rows from df1
df3[(df3.duplicated(['A','B','C','D'],keep=False)) & df3['df'] == df1)]

# if you don't want to list out all of the columns you can run it like this:
df3[(df3.duplicated(df3.loc[:,df3.columns != 'df'].columns,keep=False)) & df3['df'] == df1)]
```