# Indexing on multiple arguments that depend on each other in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas dataframe and a dictionary as defined below:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( { "c1": np.array(['a','a','b','b','a']) , "c2" : np.array([1,2,2,2,2])} )`

```
  c1  c2
0  a   1
1  a   2
2  b   2
3  b   2
4  a   2
```

`to_keep = {'a':[1],'b':[2,3]}`

```
{'a': [1], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

I want to keep those elements where both the key and one of the values of `to_keep` is true. In other words, I want to get the following dataframe:

```
  c1  c2
0  a   1
2  b   2
3  b   2
```

I have tried many things, like `df[(df["c1"] in to_keep.keys) and df["c2"] in to_keep["c1"]]`, but the thing is the I cannot pass the correct argument to the to_keep dict to get the appropriate value. I have thought of making a list of all possible combinations of `c1` and `c2`, but that may be a bit inefficient regarding the size of dataset I have.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out [lib's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338389/190597):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame( 
    { "c1": np.array(['a','a','b','b','a']) , 
      "c2": np.array([1,2,2,2,2])} )
to_keep = {'a':[1],'b':[2,3]}
to_keep = pd.DataFrame([(key, item) for key, val in to_keep.items() for item in val], 
                       columns=['c1', 'c2'])
#   c1  c2
# 0  a   1
# 1  b   2
# 2  b   3

print(pd.merge(df, to_keep, how='inner'))
```

yields

```
  c1  c2
0  a   1
1  b   2
2  b   2
```

Comment: Looks good. But is it (most) efficient? What if the number of combinations of `a` and `b` is very large?

Answer (score 2):

Try to transform to_keep in a dataframe and then merge it with the original, like in  [Compare Python Pandas DataFrames for matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464234/compare-python-pandas-dataframes-for-matching-rows)