# How to iterate through a folder of csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, iteration

I'm really new to python, so please bear with me!

I have folder on my desktop that contains a few csv files named as "File 1.csv", "File 2.csv" and so on. In each file, there is a table that looks like:

```
    Animal   Level
    Cat      1
    Dog      2
    Bird     3
    Snake    4
```

But each one of the files has a few differences in the "Animal" column. I wrote the following code that compares only two files at a time and returns the animals that match:

```
def matchlist(file1, file2): 
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    file_one = pd.read_csv(file1)
    file_two = pd.read_csv(file2)
    for i in file_one["Animal"]:
        df_temp = file_two[file_two["Animal"] == i]
        new_df = new_df.append(df_temp)
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
   return new_df
```

But that only compares two files at a time. Is there a way that will iterate through all the files in that single folder and return all the ones that match to the new_df above?

For example, new_df compares file 1 and file 2. Then, I am looking for code that compares new_df to file 3, file 4, file 5, and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it is really what you want, i can't comment yet on you questions... so:

this function returns a dataframe with animals that can be found in all csv files (can be very small) it uses the animal name as key, so the level value will not be considered

```
import pandas as pd
import os, sys

def matchlist_iter(folder_path):

    # get list with filenames in folder and throw away all non ncsv
    files = [file_path for file_path in os.listdir(folder_path) if file_path.endswith('.csv')]

    # init return df with first csv
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, files[0]), )

    for file_path in files[1:]:
        print('compare: {}'.format(file_path))
        df_other = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, file_path))

        # only keep the animals that are in both frames
        df = df_other[df['Animal'].isin(df_other['Animal'])]

    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    matched = matchlist_iter(sys.argv[1])
    print(matched)
```

---

**i've found a similar question with more answerers regarding the match here:**  [Compare Python Pandas DataFrames for matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464234/compare-python-pandas-dataframes-for-matching-rows#29571264)

**EDIT: added csv and sample output**

csv

```
Animal,  Level
Cat,      1
Dog,      2
Bird,     3
Snake,    4
```

csv

```
Animal, Level
Cat,      1
Parrot,   2
Bird,     3
Horse,    4
```

output

```
compare: csv2.csv
  Animal   Level
0    Cat       1
2   Bird       3
```

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a set of six files in which only the first columns of  `File 1.csv` and `File 6.csv` are identical.

You need only the first column of each csv for comparison purposes, I therefore arrange to extract only those from each file.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> column_1 = pd.read_csv('File 1.csv', sep='\s+')['Animal'].tolist()
>>> column_1
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Snake']
>>> for filename in Path('.').glob('*.csv'):
...     if filename.name == 'File 1.csv':
...         continue
...     next_column = pd.read_csv(filename.name, sep='\s+')['Animal'].tolist()
...     if column_1 == next_column:
...         print (filename.name)
... 
File 6.csv
```

As expected, `File 6.csv` is the only file found to be identical (in the first column) to `File 1.csv`.